# How can I write "use this cell or, if blank, use this other cell" in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to show the Days between NOW() and the dates (dd/mm/yy) in either Column B or Column C - depending which one is not blank.

```
A         B         C
29/03/10            01/04/10
29/03/10  02/04/10
29/03/10            30/04/10
29/03/10  31/03/10
29/03/10  03/04/10
```

I currently have the formula below and then drag it down, but it obviously means I need to go back and correct the "errors."

```
=ROUND(MOD(C2-A2,24),2)
```

I'm now using that instead of `=DAYS360()`. It gives me more accuracy (I think).

I always forget how to nest this type of null/blank thing, so any help or pointers to remember would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `IF` statement to achieve that as follows:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2);DAYS360(A2;C2);DAYS360(A2;B2))
```

[image]

Comment: I've shifted away from my DAYS360 to MOD and ROUND. So using your formula structure it looks like:  IF(ISBLANK(B2);ROUND(MOD(C2-A2,24),2);ROUND(MOD(B2-A2,24),2)).

Unfortunately this gives me an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should use `comma` instead of `semicolon` inside the formula. I have to use semicolon due to my regional settings.

Comment: Save some typing `=DAYS360(A2;IF(ISBLANK(B2);C2;B2))`

Comment: Changing to comma did the trick - I should have known.

Comment: Chris: Thanks I'd try your example as well, but I'm using ROUND and MOD now instead of DAYS360 - as I think it's more accurate for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but this may be useful to other readers with a similar problem.

If there is always a date in either column B or column C and the other is always blank, you don't need an IF or an ISBLANK test:

```
=DAYS360(A2,B2+C2)
```